# Send multiple images to web server with input source of imagepicker.

Tags: ios, objective-c, webserver, uiimagepickercontroller

I've used UIImagePicker to upload two images into UIImageViews. Then I sent the Two images to web server. **but instead of two different images one image saving two times**.

No problem with code what i written to send multiple images to web server.I mistaken at UIImagePicker only.This is the First time am using UIImagePicker. check the code for image picker what i written in my Project

```
- (void)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {


if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIAlertView   *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show];

}

else{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];



}


}
- (void)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
chosenImage1=info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
chosenImage2=info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

imageView.image = chosenImage;

frstCmpImgView.image= chosenImage1;
scndCmpImgView.image=chosenImage2;


if ([self.navigationItem.title  isEqual: @"CLOTHING"]) {
    NSLog(@"cloth page");
    [self clothview];
}
else if([self.navigationItem.title  isEqual: @"FACE PHOTO"]){


    [self hideButtns];

    NSLog(@"face page");

}

else{
    //----compare object--

    if ([cmparObjLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Choose the 1st Object"]) {
        [self afterUploadFrstCmpObj];

    }
    else if ([cmparObjLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Choose the 2nd Object"])
    {

        [self afterUploadScndCmpObj];
    }
}
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Thanks in advance for every one.

Comment: here u r pass the single image in 2 variables , see this your mistake chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
chosenImage1=info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

Comment: then how to modify this